# На что указывает этот роутер:

Tags: node.js

На что будет указывать этот роутер:

```
app.get('/:id',(req,res)=>{
  //
});
```

Answer (score 1):

На корень сайта. При этом то, что в адресе после слеша, будет доступно из ключа `req.params.id`

Например при адресе `http://example.com/12345` в `req.params.id` будет значение 12345.

По сути :id - это название переменной